# TCP Server return the recieve message to all client except the sender in C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, qnx

This is my code

Server.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define PORT 4444
#define BUF_SIZE 2000
#define CLADDR_LEN 100

void main() {
    struct sockaddr_in addr, cl_addr;
    int sockfd, len, ret, newsockfd,clientnumber;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    pid_t childpid;
    char clientAddr[CLADDR_LEN];


    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        printf("Error creating socket!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Socket created...\n");

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = PORT;

    ret = bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Error binding!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Binding done...\n");
    clientnumber = 0;
    printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");
    listen(sockfd, 5);

    for (;;) { //infinite loop
        len = sizeof(cl_addr);
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, &len);
        if (newsockfd < 0) {
            printf("Error accepting connection!\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Connection accepted...\n");
        clientnumber++;
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &(cl_addr.sin_addr), clientAddr, CLADDR_LEN);
        if ((childpid = fork()) == 0) { //creating a child process

            close(sockfd);
            //stop listening for new connections by the main process.
            //the child will continue to listen.
            //the main process now handles the connected client.


            sprintf(buffer, "USER%d", clientnumber);
            ret = sendto(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, len);
            if (ret < 0){
                printf("Allocate Client number error\n");
                exit(1);
            }else{
                printf("Passing Client number : %d to Client Address %s ,  Newsockfd : %d ,claddr %d : \n",clientnumber,clientAddr,newsockfd,cl_addr);

            }


            for (;;) {
                memset(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);
                ret = recvfrom(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, &len);
                if(ret < 0) {
                    printf("Error receiving data! from %s\n",clientAddr);
                    exit(1);
                }

                printf("Received data from %s(%d): %s\n", clientAddr,cl_addr.sin_addr.s_addr, buffer);


                ret = sendto(newsockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &cl_addr, len);
                if (ret < 0) {
                    printf("Error sending data! to %s\n",clientAddr);
                    exit(1);
                }
                printf("Sent data to %s: %s   Newsockfd : %d ,claddr %d :\n", clientAddr, buffer,newsockfd,cl_addr);

            }


        }
        close(newsockfd);
    }
}
```

Client.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>



#define PORT 4444
#define BUF_SIZE 2000
#define MAX_SIZE    1024
#define MSG_STOP    "exit"

#define CHECK(x) \
        do { \
            if (!(x)) { \
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: ", __func__, __LINE__); \
                perror(#x); \
                exit(-1); \
            } \
        } while (0) \

int createQUEUE_NAMEInSharedMemory(char * QUEUE_NAME ){
    char buffer[80], filename[200] = "/tmp/chat.txt";
    int fd, file_size, ret, size_written, size_read;
    void *addr;

    unlink( filename);
    fd = open( filename, O_CREAT|O_RDWR , 0777 );
    if( fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_written = write( fd, QUEUE_NAME, strlen(QUEUE_NAME) + 1 );
    if ( size_written == -1 ){
        perror("write");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf( "Wrote %d bytes into file %s\n", size_written, filename );

    lseek( fd, 0L, SEEK_SET );
    file_size = lseek( fd, 0L, SEEK_END );
    printf( "Size of file = %d bytes\n", file_size );

    /* Map the file into memory. */
    addr = mmap( 0, file_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE , MAP_SHARED,
            fd, 0 );
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Change the memory and synchronize it with the disk. */
    //                  memset( addr, 'B', 2 );
    //                  ret = msync( addr, file_size, MS_SYNC);
    //                  if( ret == -1) {
    //                      perror("msync");
    //                      exit(0);
    //                  }

    /* Close and reopen the file, and then read its contents. */
    close(fd);
    fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY);
    if( fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_read = read( fd, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
    printf( "File content = %s\n", buffer );

    close(fd);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



int main(){
    struct sockaddr_in addr, cl_addr;
    int sockfd, ret;
    char buffer[BUF_SIZE];
    struct hostent * server;
    char * serverAddr;
    char QUEUE_NAME[100];
    char * clientnumber;
    char temp[200];
    serverAddr = "127.0.0.1";
    printf("Server IP Address = %s\n",serverAddr);

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        printf("Error creating socket!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Socket created...\n");

    memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(serverAddr);
    addr.sin_port = PORT;

    ret = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Error connecting to the server!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Connected to the server...\n");
    ret = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        printf("Error receiving data!\n");
    } else {
        clientnumber = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(clientnumber, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
        clientnumber = realloc(clientnumber, strlen(clientnumber));
        sprintf(QUEUE_NAME, "/%s", clientnumber);

        printf("Received USER ID: ");
        fputs(buffer, stdout);
        printf("\n");

    }

    ret = createQUEUE_NAMEInSharedMemory(QUEUE_NAME);
    if(ret < 0){
        printf("Error Creating QUERE_NAME : %s !\n",QUEUE_NAME);
    }else{
        printf("Sending QUERE_NAME (%s) to shared memory successful!\n",QUEUE_NAME);
        mqd_t mq;
        struct mq_attr attr;
        char buffer[MAX_SIZE + 1];
        int must_stop = 0;

        /* initialize the queue attributes */
        attr.mq_flags = 0;
        attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
        attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_SIZE;
        attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

        /* create the message queue */
        mq = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644, &attr);
        CHECK((mqd_t)-1 != mq);
        printf("Creating MSG QUERE_NAME : %s \n",QUEUE_NAME);
        do {
            ssize_t bytes_read;

            /* receive the message */
            bytes_read = mq_receive(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, NULL);
            CHECK(bytes_read >= 0);

            buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
            if (! strncmp(buffer, MSG_STOP, strlen(MSG_STOP)))
            {
                must_stop = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Received: %s\n", buffer);
                 memcpy(temp, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
                sprintf(buffer, "%s:%s", clientnumber,temp);
                 mq_send(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0);
                ret = sendto(sockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
                if (ret < 0) {
                    printf("Error sending data!\n\t-%s", buffer);
                }

                ret = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);
                                if (ret < 0) {
                                    printf("Error receiving data!\n");
                                } else {
                                     mq_send(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0);
                                }


            }
        } while (!must_stop);
        printf("STOP MSG QUERE_NAME : %s \n",QUEUE_NAME);
        /* cleanup */
        CHECK((mqd_t)-1 != mq_close(mq));
        CHECK((mqd_t)-1 != mq_unlink(QUEUE_NAME));
    }



    //  memset(buffer, 0, BUF_SIZE);
    //  printf("%s: ",QUEUE_NAME);

    //  while (fgets(buffer, BUF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
    //          ret = sendto(sockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &addr, sizeof(addr));
    //          if (ret < 0) {
    //              printf("Error sending data!\n\t-%s", buffer);
    //          }
    //          ret = recvfrom(sockfd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0, NULL, NULL);
    //          if (ret < 0) {
    //              printf("Error receiving data!\n");
    //          } else {
    //              printf("Received: ");
    //              fputs(buffer, stdout);
    //              printf("\n");
    //              //printf("Enter your message(s): ");
    //              printf("%s: ",QUEUE_NAME);
    //          }
    //      }
    free(clientnumber);
    return 0;
}
```

Input.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_SIZE    1024
#define MSG_STOP    "exit"

#define CHECK(x) \
        do { \
            if (!(x)) { \
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: ", __func__, __LINE__); \
                perror(#x); \
                exit(-1); \
            } \
        } while (0) \


char QUEUE_NAME[100];

void GetQUERENAME(){
    char buffer[80], filename[200] = "/tmp/chat.txt";
    int fd, file_size, ret, size_written, size_read;
    void *addr;

    fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY);
    if( fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_read = read( fd, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
    //printf( "File content = %s\n", buffer );
    memcpy(QUEUE_NAME, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
    //printf("QUEUE_NAME length = %d\n",strlen(QUEUE_NAME));
    close(fd);
}



int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    GetQUERENAME();
    mqd_t mq;
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE];

    /* open the mail queue */
    mq = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_WRONLY);
    CHECK((mqd_t)-1 != mq);


    printf("Send to Client QUERE_NAME : %s (enter \"exit\" to stop it):\n",QUEUE_NAME);

    do {
        printf("> ");
        fflush(stdout);

        memset(buffer, 0, MAX_SIZE);
        fgets(buffer, MAX_SIZE, stdin);

        /* send the message */
        CHECK(0 <= mq_send(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0));

    } while (strncmp(buffer, MSG_STOP, strlen(MSG_STOP)));

    /* cleanup */
    CHECK((mqd_t)-1 != mq_close(mq));




    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

output.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_SIZE    1024
#define MSG_STOP    "exit"

#define CHECK(x) \
        do { \
            if (!(x)) { \
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: ", __func__, __LINE__); \
                perror(#x); \
                exit(-1); \
            } \
        } while (0) \


char QUEUE_NAME[100];

void GetQUERENAME(){
    char buffer[80], filename[200] = "/tmp/chat.txt";
    int fd, file_size, ret, size_written, size_read;
    void *addr;

    fd = open( filename, O_RDONLY);
    if( fd == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    size_read = read( fd, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) );
//  printf( "File content = %s\n", buffer );
    memcpy(QUEUE_NAME, buffer, strlen(buffer)+1);
//  printf("QUEUE_NAME length = %d\n",strlen(QUEUE_NAME));
    close(fd);
}



int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    GetQUERENAME();
    mqd_t mq;
    struct mq_attr attr;
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE + 1];
    int must_stop = 0;

    /* initialize the queue attributes */
    attr.mq_flags = 0;
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
    attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_SIZE;
    attr.mq_curmsgs = 0;

    /* create the message queue */
    mq = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0644, &attr);
    CHECK((mqd_t)-1 != mq);

    do {
        ssize_t bytes_read;

        /* receive the message */
        bytes_read = mq_receive(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, NULL);
        CHECK(bytes_read >= 0);

        buffer[bytes_read] = '\0';
        if (! strncmp(buffer, MSG_STOP, strlen(MSG_STOP)))
        {
            must_stop = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
        }
    } while (!must_stop);

    /* cleanup */
    CHECK((mqd_t)-1 != mq_close(mq));
    CHECK((mqd_t)-1 != mq_unlink(QUEUE_NAME));

    return 0;
}
```

So I try to have a server that accept client via tcp protocol. next I try to make a program like group chat. at the testing process every client it connect from the same IP address. after client connect to the server. client will can sending message to server and vice versa. at the current process it does only return message to the sender. I want to know how to act like broadcast to send the message to every client except the sender. thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First step - ditch the call to `fork()`. Having each client served by a completely separate process isn't going to make it easy to have them be aware and able to interact with each other. It's much easier to have the server handle all the clients.

Here is some semi-pseudo code of how such a main loop might look like.

```
while(1)
  {
  FD_ZERO(&readfds);
  FD_SET(sockfd,&readfds);
  for(each client FD)
    {
    FD_SET(clientfd,&readfds);
    }
  select(maxfds,&readfds,NULL,NULL,NULL);
  if(FD_ISSET(sockfd,&readfds))
    {
    /* accept() a new client */;
    }
  for(each client FD)
    {
    if(FD_ISSET(clientfd,&readfds))
      {
      /* read input */
      }
    }
  }
```

You'll want to buffer the input from the clients so you can send complete lines to everyone else otherwise it'll be a mess to read what people are writing. And handle clients disconnecting. And probably some way to identify which client is saying stuff.

If you go looking, there are countless examples of finished MUDs and Talkers that you can look at to get an idea how they do what you're doing though.